# Outlook calendar not showing the correct time for timezones?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, outlook-calendar

i am working on a process in which i have to create and ics file and send it via email attachment. The process also includes "Add To Calendar" links to add event in calendars. All links are working fine except outlook. Outlook calendar does not converts time according to timezone perhaps. 
Gcal and yahoo calendar are showing correct time. Here is sample link for outlook.

```
https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/view/Month&startdt=2018-12-08T10%3a00%3a00-05%3a00&enddt=2018-12-08T10%3a30%3a00-05%3a00&subject=Vein+Appointment+Confirmation&body=Vein+Clinics+of+America+Alexandria+Appointment&location=4900+Seminary+Road+Suite+100+Alexandria%2c+VA+22311
```

i also changed the timezone of outlook. i am using PKT timezone. Time should be 6am – 6:30am according to timezone. while outlook showing it as 8:20PM to 8:50 PM.
thanks

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook calendar process your params from GET query as UTC time, the format is  `YYYYMMDDTHHmmSS`. You can find more information here: https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/master/services/outlook-live.md (feel free to contribute if you know more (it's easy))